# Sum the values of an array if their id's are the same

Tags: php, mysql

Please see table below:

## items

```
id  title   fields
1   Dog     [{"id":"11","value":"50"},{"id":"19","value":"100"},{"id":"22","value":"150"}]
2   Cat     [{"id":"19","value":"50"},{"id":"22","value":"100"},{"id":"37","value":"150"}]
3   Bird    [{"id":"14","value":"50"},{"id":"19","value":"100"},{"id":"22","value":"150"}]
4   Mouse   [{"id":"16","value":"50"},{"id":"22","value":"100"},{"id":"34","value":"150"}]
5   Horse   [{"id":"6","value":"50"},{"id":"22","value":"100"},{"id":"47","value":"150"}]
```

I want to echo the sum of all the values that equals to id 22
I am a complete novice to php and mysql and will appreciate any assistance, so please explain the code to me clearly.

This is what I have found, but does not work:

```
<?php
    if ($fields->id == 22) {
        $result += $fields['value'];
    }
    return $result;
?>
```

please help.... thank you

Comment: Do "var_dump($array);" and post the result in your question above please.

Comment: can you show what is the result of `var_dump($fields)`;Also i guess you need to loop throught he items and find the sum.

Comment: are the values json_encoded? What does your actual array look like?

Comment: after investigation i can confirm that it is json data and that i've tried Sankalp's answer, but with no success. You refer to var_dump.... I have no idea what you are talking about or even where i need to enter that code. I did however add it to the php output file and the only result i received was NULL, if that makes any sense. I tried both answers below, but not working.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like $fields is json data. If it is, then

Try this:

```
    $data = json_decode($fields);
    foreach($data as $element) {
      if ($fields->id == 22) {
         $result += intval($fields->value);
      }
    }
    return $result;
```